# Which ADFS claim maps to Identity.Name by default?

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, adfs

Did ADFS change recently with respect to how the `upn` gets mapped to `User.Identity.Name` in ASP.NET?

What I know:

- ASP.NET web app that authenticates externally via ADFS
- test environment worked OK with no outgoing `Name` claim defined in ADFS a few months ago
- test environment was fired up recently and ADFS login failed. ADFS server did not have any configuration changes
- issue is that `User.Identity.Name` is `null` even though `Request.IsAuthenticated` is `true`
- root cause is that there is no `Name` claim and there appears to be no explicit mapping in web.config to use `upn` for this

From Microsoft:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt740689(v=vs.85).aspx

> When you pass a valid security token to the AD FS Web Agent, it
>   creates an session cookie and processes the token's claims into the
>   session's User object. This object is derived from IPrincipal, and
>   exposes one method, IsInRole(), with which you can query the User and
>   determine whether that user asserts the specified role claim (using a
>   string to specify the role).
>
> IPrincipal also exposes one property, Identity, which returns the
>   user's identity, represented as an IIdentity object. This object can
>   be used by the default.aspx page to determine whether the User is
>   authenticated (by calling IsAuthenticated(). It also allows you to
>   determine whether the user is asserting a name claim by accessing the
>   Name property, which returns a string representing the User's name.
>   The snippet here illustrates the use of both of these techniques.

I have questions about this that I can't find in Microsoft docs:

1. What specifically is meant (as in: which xml attribute or specific ADFS claim string) by "the user is asserting a name claim" ? (it is ambiguous: is it "name" claim? because it reads more like "name claim" where "name" could be loosely defined as user name, and often `upn` is used for this, and was working in the past)
2. What is the exact logic used by .NET for setting `User.Identity.Name` when using configuration-based identity with ADFS (defined in web.config)?

Comment: forgot to mention one critical detail: of course creating the `Name` claim and mapping from `upn` makes it all work again, but we are trying to solve the mystery and also trying to justify to IT why ADFS claims suddenly need to change. any input helps thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this "Name" logic did not change in the latest versions of the framework.
As explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.defaultnameclaimtype?view=netframework-4.7.1) for instance, by default the claim type used to populate the `Identity.Name` property has always been:
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name

So if your SAML token contains such claim, it will be used as the "name" of the user (it is up to you to decide which AD attribute you want to put in this claim: userPrincipalName, displayName, mail, ...).

This default attribute can be overriden in code, or in your web.config. [This page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbertocci/2010/05/11/a-hidden-gem-the-wif-config-schema/) mentions a "`<nameClaimType />`" element, honestly I don't remember if it has changed in the meantime.
a
Note: your link is really old. The "ADFS Web Agent" was something from the first version of ADFS, but it was rapidely superseded by WIF.

Comment: Thanks. This is accurate, and answers my question, but in the end turns out I actually did break it with an inadvertent change, and then failed to see this because I was simply looking at the wrong branch. oops. It turns out ADFS wasn't supposed to be using Identity.Name at all because we end up constructing a `GenericIdentity` after parsing the username claim (which is a configurable key, but usually is `upn`)